# How is there a convergent limit in this simple formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence, finance

All details are in the attached picture. Please refer to it.

Here are some examples I calculated with different first year operating margins(in case it might help you):

Example #1: When terminal year operating margin = 14.18% and my speed of convergence = 1:

Yr 0 = -4.18%, Yr 1 = 5%, Yr 2 = 9.6%, Yr 3 = 11.9%, Yr 4 = 13.04%, Yr 5 = 13.62%, Yr 6 = 13.91%, Yr 7 = 14.05%, Yr 8 = 14.12%, Yr 9 = 14.16%, Yr 10 = 14.18%, Yr 11 (Terminal value) = 14.19%

Example #2: When terminal year operating margin = 100% and my speed of convergence = 1:

Yr 0 = 100%, Yr 1 = 57.10%, Yr 2 = 35.65%, Yr 3 = 24.92%, Yr 4 = 19.56%, Yr 5 = 16.88%, Yr 6 = 15.53%, Yr 7 = 14.86%, Yr 8 = 14.53%, Yr 9 = 14.36%, Yr 10 = 14.28%, Yr 11 (Terminal value) = 14.19%

[image]

Also, I want to know how can one make better formulas that convergent to a given value. Does anyone have any appropriate resources/methodology they could share?

Comment: It would more understandable for you and the community if you wrote equations using symbols instead of writing sentences in the equation.

Comment: I don't know latex but I added a picture with better symbols!

Comment: @YashMehta How about learning LaTeX?

Comment: @Gary haha did you downvote my post? I'm just a newbie to this subreddit and in the process of learning Latex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing 11 times the average between a number and $14.19$: calling $x_n$ the operating margin at Year $n$, you have

$$x_n=\frac{1}{2}x_{n-1}+\frac{14.19}{2}=\frac{1}{4}(x_{n-2}+14.19)+\frac{14.19}{2}=\frac{1}{4}x_{n-2}+\frac{3}{4}14.19=\\
=\dots=\frac{1}{2^n}x_0+(1-\frac{1}{2^n})14.19.$$

Considering the fact that $2^{11}=2048$, and you consider only 2 decimals you have $$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{11}}\right)14.19=14.18.$$

Moreover, choosing $x_0\in(10,100)$, $\frac{1}{2^{11}}x_0\in(0.0005,0.005)$ which is almost enough to reach $14.19$, and you have also  rounding errors that sums up, so it is quite understandable that the convergence seems perfect.

If you try with huge numbers, it won't be the case. Indeed, for $x_0=2048$, you will have $$x_{11}=1+\frac{2047}{2048}14.19=1+14.18=15.18.$$

In particular, choose $a$ to be any number, and take $x_0=2048\,a+14.19$, hence $x_{11}=a$.

**EDIT**

The general case, can be written as follows: let $x_0$ be the initial operating margin, $s$ the speed of convergence, hence

$$x_n=\frac{s}{1+s}x_{n-1}+\frac{14.19}{1+s}=\frac{s}{(1+s)^2}(s\,x_{n-2}+14.19)+\frac{14.19}{1+s}=\\ \left(\frac{s}{1+s}\right)^2 x_{n-2}+\left(1-\frac{s^2}{(1+s)^2}\right)14.19=\dots=\\ =\left(\frac{s}{1+s}\right)^n x_0+\left(1-\left(\frac{s}{1+s}\right)^n\right)14.19.$$

Since $\left(\frac{s}{1+s}\right)^n\to0$, it is clear that for $n$ big enough, it converges to $14.19$, the fact is that depending on the choice of $x_0$ and $s$, *big enough* can be bigger or smaller than 11, which is the number you want.

In particular, with the equation above, putting n=11, you can play with $s$ and $x_0$ and see how far you are from the convergence.

Comment: I get that you are doing averages between two numbers. But how is it a good convergence? If I choose X0 = 5 and not 10 like you said, it will stop at 16.88% yeah.

Comment: Hey man. I added a picture with another example (in good formatting!) that I calculated. Could you please help me understand why the discrepancy is occuring between my calculated value and how to make a better formula?

Comment: I edited the previous answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your edited answer! My doubt is solved. But I was wondering what is the method used to create a convergence formula like this.

Comment: And if I have a pre-determined range of -50<= x0 <= 50 and 1<= s <= 2, what would be the best way to fine-tune this formula to get better results?

Comment: If you have more questions, Yash, you should post them as new questions (and include links between the new questions and this one) instead of pestering user ecrin.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Noted. My intention wasn't to pester, just ask further questions because he was the only one who replied and wrote a long answer despite my question already having 55 views.

Comment: Maybe, Yash, if you put some effort into learning how to format mathematics on this site, your question would have drawn more replies. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference is a good place to start. Or https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto

Comment: Noted Gerry. Will do. Thanks for the starting resources!